Ubuntu 20.04 update broke my laptop. Managed to install Ubuntu 24.04, is everything okay?
I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus laptop (specs at the bottom of the post) since it was released without any problem. But a few days ago, the typical updater window came up. I installed the updates without giving it too much attention (so I don't know the version of the update) and pressed restart when the updater asked me to. However, after shutting down, Ubuntu couldn't boot up again. I got a black screen with a few firmware error messages like ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer.
My partner and I looked it up and thought it was likely some issue with updated drivers (the most reported, Nvidia drivers, although my laptop doesn't have Nvidia). We tried some fixes we found on askubuntu, like removing the Nvidia drivers from the recovery mode (which was the only way we could access Ubuntu), but nothing worked. We even formatted the disk and reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 (the only distro I had a live USB prepared for), but even from a fresh installation, it wouldn't boot up, only from recovery mode.
The next day we tried installing the newer Ubuntu version, 24.04, also erasing the disk, and hoping that it wouldn't come with "broken" drivers (?). And thank goodness it worked. Everything seems normal, except for two things. It takes a few seconds longer to boot up (which I guess is normal since it is a newer version?). But what bugs me is that, after pressing the power button, the Asus logo appears alone, a few seconds pass, I get a black screen and with a blink of an eye the Asus logo appears again, this time with the Ubuntu logo down below. With Ubuntu 20.04 the Ubuntu logo always appeared along with the Asus logo right after turning the laptop on.
So I have a few questions:

Why after erasing the disk completely (I guess completely, it wasn't hard as I only have one partition) and reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04, it still couldn't boot up? Is it because during installation the same, latest updates that caused the error were installed again? Or because they were installed from the beginning somewhere that the Ubuntu installer couldn't detect so Ubuntu 20.04 was installed on top of them? (Sorry I don't know much of how this goes).
Is my new installation of Ubuntu 24.04 safe? I hope everything that "corrupted" my Ubuntu 20.04 is gone now... and that everything we tried on grub or recovery mode does not affect Ubuntu 24.04 either...
Is it normal that the Asus logo shows up alone for a few seconds before the Ubuntu logo?

Asus ZenBook UM431DA specs:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700U
GPU (integrated): AMD Radeon Vega 10 Graphics
RAM: 16GB DDR4


Seem to be kernel issue. Some Radeon GPU can prevent to boot Ubuntu 24.04 and got blackscreen. Switch kernel can help. Or, remove splash in Grub file to boot. See same issue here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1526062/1928225
